# Are coreboot and/or SeaBIOS questions appropriate here?

Tags: discussion, support

Are questions related to [coreboot](https://www.coreboot.org/) and/or [SeaBIOS](https://seabios.org/SeaBIOS) appropriate on this Stack Exchange? If not, which one would be more appropriate? Server Fault? They're kinda mean.

Comment: I don't know enough about either to judge. Do they have anything to do wit *nix? Embedded *nix systems are on topic, is that what these are? Server Fault is for professional sysadmins, if that's not what you are, don't go there. Would [iot.se] be an option?

Comment: Hey @terdon, Coreboot is an open source BIOS, for which you can pair with a payload such as SeaBIOS, Linux, GRUB, or some other options. You load this onto your BIOS chip with a programmer and stick it onto your motherboard. I believe it uses some linux code to do some basic hardware initialisation. (that means you can install linux on your bios chip, and boot straight to it without having any disc at all!)

Comment: In that case I would say it's not on topic since it's at a lower level than the OS. I won't post an answer yet, in case someone with a better understanding wants to. Your best bet will probably be [su] though.

Comment: Ah yes super user! Thanks terdon.